# vue.js cambiar bool de 1/0 a si/no

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js

desde un api recibo un boolean en 1 o 0

JSON

```
    {
        "Nombre": "Andres",
        "IdiomaNativo": 1
    }
```

Como puedo hacer para cambiar esto en el frontend con Vue.js y hacer que si es 1me imprima un Si y si es 0 un No

adjunto la imagen para que vean como se ve
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lZGo.png

```
por ahora solo lo recorro 
    <div id="info">
      <div v-for="data in results">
       <span class="personInfo"> Nombre Completo: </span> {{data.titulo}} {{data.Nombre}} {{data.segundoNombre}} {{data.Apellido}} {{data.Sufijo}} <br>
       <span class="personInfo"> Tipo Nombre: </span> {{data.titulo}} {{data.Apellido}}  <span v-for="first in firstNameLetter">{{first}}</span> {{data.Sufijo}}<br>
       <span class="personInfo"> Nativo: </span> {{data.IdiomaNativo}} <br> <!--se podria poner en vez de 1 un si-->
       <span class="personInfo"> Porcentaje de dominio: </span> {{data.NivelDominio}}<br>
       <hr>
      </div>
```

Comment: {{data.IdiomaNativo?'SI':'NO'}}

Answer (score 1):

Una de las formas más límpias es hacer un método (dentro de methods) que haga el parseo de la respuesta, le quedaría algo así:

```
resultOfRequest = { "Nombre": "Andres", "IdiomaNativo": 1 }


function parseLanguaje(nativeLanguage) {
  return {
    1: 'Si',
    2: 'No'
  }[nativeLanguage]
}

function data(resultOfRequest) {
  return { ...resultOfRequest, IdiomaNativo: parseLanguaje(resultOfRequest.IdiomaNativo)}
}
```

Con eso no depende de la inferencia automática que hace javascript. Recuerde que debe colocar la menor cantidad del lógica dentro del renderizado HTML. En este caso `data` sería lo que devuelve a la vista.